# Finding orthonormal basis for inner product in P2(C)

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

Let $p, q \in P_2(\Bbb C)$.  Define the inner product by

$$\langle p(x), q(x)\rangle = \int_0^1 p(x) \overline{q(x)} \, dx $$

How do I find orthonormal basis for inner product space?

Comment: Do you know [Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process)?

Comment: Yes, I do but I think I only know how to do it with specified vectors like {[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[2,2,1]} or something.

Comment: If you know a basis of an inner product space $V$, Gram-Schmidt gives you an orthogonal basis of $V$.  So do you know of a basis for $P_2(\Bbb C)$?

Comment: I know of the standard basis [1,x,$x^2$], so is it {[1,0,0],[0,x,0],[0,0,$x^2$]}?

Comment: No, you need to use the standard basis in the orthogonalization process.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, given a basis $\beta = \{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ of an inner product space $V$, applying the [Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) will produce an orthogonal basis $\gamma = \{u_1, \ldots, u_n\}$ for $V$.  We can compute the $u_i$ using the formula given in the link:
$$
u_k = v_k - \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \frac{\langle u_j, v_k \rangle}{\langle u_j, u_j \rangle} u_j \, .
$$

So we begin with the standard basis $\beta = \{1, x, x^2\}$.  We can take $u_1 = 1$, so to find $u_2$ we need to compute
$$
u_2 = x - \frac{\langle 1, x \rangle}{\langle 1, 1 \rangle} 1 \, .
$$
Now
\begin{align*}
\langle 1, 1 \rangle &= \int_0^1 1 \, \overline{1} \ dx = 1&
&&\langle 1, x \rangle &= \int_0^1 1 \, \overline{x} \ dx = \left. \frac{x^2}{2} \right|_0^1 = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}
so
$$
u_2 = x - \frac{\langle 1, x \rangle}{\langle 1, 1 \rangle} 1 = x - \frac{1/2}{1} 1 = x - \frac{1}{2} \, .
$$
Can you use the formula to compute $u_3$?  Once you've done that, don't forget to normalize your vectors so they all have length $1$.